# Why map is creating NULL in C++?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have a 2D vector of string as

```
vector<vector<string>> database
```

it has following data

```
database[0] -> A C D   (database[0][0] -> A , database[0][1] -> C and so on)  
database[1] -> B C E F
database[2] -> A B C E F
database[3] -> B E
database[4] -> A C F
```

I am counting the occurrence of each `string` (in this example each character A,B etc.) and saving it in a `map` `map_c` as

```
map<string,int> map_c ;

   for(i=0 ; i<database.size() ; i++)
    {
        for(j=0 ; j<database.at(i).size() ; j++)
        {
            if(map_c.find(database.at(i).at(j)) != map_c.end())
            {
                map_c[database[i][j]]++;                
            }
            else
            {
                map_c[database[i][j]] = 1;
            }
        }

    }
```

And printing the count of each string using the code

```
for(map<string,int>::iterator it = map_c.begin() ; it != map_c.end() ; it++ )
{
    cout << it->first << " -> " << it->second << endl;
}
```

Output ->

```
  -> 1
A -> 3
B -> 3
C -> 4
D -> 1
E -> 3
F -> 3
```

**Why NULL key has been created with a count 1 ?**

Comment: `std::map`'s `[]` will default construct objects that are not in the map and zero init pointers and number values, so you should not need the extra case to set the `1` value. But guessing that you have an extra entry you are not expecting.

Comment: Maybe you have a whitespace in your `database`?

Comment: Are you sure it's NULL, not just ' ' (space)? Are you sure your vectors don't have that space somewhere?

Comment: use `std::cout << database[i][j] << " " << i ":"<< j << '\n'; ` in `else` part to figure out which entry is the culprit

Comment: Just curious as to why you're using `at`, rather than `[]`, when indexing into the array.  Do you really expect a bounds error, and have a catch block somewhere to recover from it?

Comment: yes,m sure,my database does not contain whitespace .

Comment: @JamesKanze yes u r right, there is no meaning of using at instead of [] without exception handling . I am new to STL lib of C++ , so i am just enjoying and practicing these functions which STL provides.

Answer (score 4):

The code you post should not generate an empty (or spaces) string. It is possible such a string comes with your initial data.

Either way, your code to fill the map can be made much much shorter:

```
map<string,int> map_c ;
for(const auto& line: database)
    for(const auto& s: line)
        ++map_c[s];
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace your `if...else` with just `++map_c[database[i][j]];`  . The default value for `int` in a map is `0`.

The unexpected entry in your output is because your `database` actually had that entry in it.  If you are not sure why this entry is in your database, review the code that sets up your database (and/or post that code).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry , finaly i got rid the problem. Problem was in the input file. At the end of the file , there was a space character at last line and i was thinking that my file has been over before it . That space was creating the problem. I am sorry for inconvenience and thank you so much for your replies and time .